# When i filter dataset in Python how to save filtered data in excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

```
print(Katalog_final.apply(lambda row: row[Katalog_final['PROGRAM (robna grupa)'].isin(['Alkoholna pića','Bezalkoholna pića','Prerada voća povrća i med'])]))
```

This is Form which i want to save in excel delete others form

```
78       Banjalucka pivara doo Banjaluka        743840             PIVO NEKTAR 0,5l LIM. 10+2 GRATIS  3.877002e+12        Alkoholna pića
179  Molson Coors BH d.o.o.                      305747           Pivo 0,5 l limenka 4/1 Staropramen   8.600105e+12        Alkoholna pića
180       Banjalucka pivara doo Banjaluka        208470                    Pivo 0,33l Six Pack Nektar  3.871137e+12        Alkoholna pića
..                                    ...           ...                                           ...           ...                   ...
322  Venera doo                                  309771           Vino Spricer Bijeli 4,5% 0,5l Rubin  8.600074e+12        Alkoholna pića
323  Venera doo                                  309770       Vino Spricer Rose 4,5% alc. 0,5 l Rubin  8.600074e+12        Alkoholna pića
324                     Mladost trade doo        105193         Vino Vranac Pro Corde 0,75 l Plantaže  3.899003e+12        Alkoholna pića
325                     Mladost trade doo        105138                    Vino Vranac 0,75l Plantaže  8.600143e+12        Alkoholna pića
326                     Mladost trade doo        105142                Vino Chardonay 0,75 l Platnaže  8.600143e+12        Alkoholna pića
```

Comment: give the filtered `df_filtered` a name and then `df_filtered.to_excel('mydf.xlsx')`

Comment: Like Kavi said.                                                                                                                          df_filtered = Katalog_final.apply(lambda row: row[Katalog_final['PROGRAM (robna grupa)'].isin(['Alkoholna pića','Bezalkoholna pića','Prerada voća povrća i med'])]))      df_filtered.to_excel('mydf.xlsx')